# If first condition is true, check to see if values in multiple adjacent cells match

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a list of names in column A on two separate sheets. Then, in columns B, C, and D - I have a Y or N. I'm trying to check the difference between sheet 1 and sheet 2.

Formula Function:
Check for value in Sheet1!A1 in Sheet2!A:A
If Sheet1!A1 matches (for example) Sheet2!A4,
Then check Sheet1B1:D1 against Sheet2!B4:D4
Return Match or No Match.

If Sheet1!A1 doesn't match any value in Sheet2!A:A, Return N/A

I've tried a couple dozen different combinations of VLookups, INDEX MATCH with an IF and AND to get it to confirm all three values, but can't seem to figure out how to combine all 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [COUNTIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/countifs-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842) is what you're looking for.  Based on your description, something like this should work for you:

`=IF(COUNTIF(Sheet2!A:A,Sheet1!A1)=0,"N/A",IF(COUNTIFS(Sheet2!A:A,Sheet1!A1,Sheet2!B:B,Sheet1!B1,Sheet2!C:C,Sheet1!C1,Sheet2!D:D,Sheet1!D1)=0,"No Match","Match"))`

Comment: Thank you very much... this worked perfectly. Did not even occur to my to use a conditional COUNTIF.

Answer (score 0):

)

Try this (at home I have only the Dutch version, but tried my best to translate it to English formulas):

`=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP($A1;Sheet2!$A:$D;1;0));"N/A";IF(AND(VLOOKUP($A1;Sheet2!$A:$D;1;0)=$A1;VLOOKUP($A1;Sheet2!$A:$D;2;0)=$B1;VLOOKUP($A1;Sheet2!$A:$D;3;0)=$C1;VLOOKUP($A1;Sheet2!$A:$D;4;0)=$D1);"Match";"No Match"))`

NOTE: This means the data in rows B:D on Sheet1 are in the exact same order as on Sheet2. If not, it will result in a "No Match".